# Make auto.arima in R search wider model space

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the auto.arima function in R, however I believe it's not searching a wide enough state space, I don't want to set stepwise to false because I dont have the resources for that, however is there a way to have the algorithm search a wider space (i.e more values of p,d and q) ?

Current trace:

```
mod_TV_rev<-auto.arima(ts.data[,9],xreg=cbind.data.frame(xreg,fourier(ts.data[,9],K = K) )
                       ,approximation=F,parallel =T ,num.cores = 3,stepwise=T,trace=T,max.order = 12 ,stationary = T,seasonal=T)

ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean : Inf *
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : 1517.568
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : 1520.413
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf *
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     : 1512.052
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : 1520.413
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf *
 ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf *

 Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the maximum seasonal and non-seasonal AR, MA and differencing orders using `max.p`, `max.P` etc. - see `?auto.arima`.

However, unless you set `stepwise=F`, `auto.arima` will proceed greedily and terminate when it cannot improve any more - and note that your trace shows it got nowhere near the default maximum orders. (And those default values make a lot of sense. You *very* rarely should consider higher orders than 5.)

Alternatives are:

1. setting `stepwise=FALSE`, which you don't have the resources for
2. modifying the `auto.arima` code so it accepts a temporary worsening in its stopping criterion before terminating
3. deciding on certain models beforehand and fitting them directly, using `arima`
4. thinking *hard* about your problem - if `auto.arima` does not want to go beyond order 2, it probably has good reasons. What's your rationale for wanting to expand the search space?

Answer (score 0):

`max.order =` will only be used when `stepwise = FALSE`. There are, however, arguments you can use when `stepwise = TRUE`: `start.p`, `start.P`, `start.q`, and `start.Q` allow you set the starting values in the stepwise search. You can also specify `max.d` and `max.D`.

Comment: I've tried setting starting values but it still doesn't search a wide a range as I'd like.

Comment: Are you sure your time series is stationary and seasonal? If not, try omitting both of those arguments, as including them will limit the model space that is searched.

Comment: Also, I should point out that the `parallel` (and related `num.cores`) arguments are ignored when `stepwise = TRUE`